# How to parse json data retreived from ajax call

Tags: jquery, json, ajax

I have used ajax

```
function pull_data(url)
{
    //var _data;
    return $.ajax(
    {
        url: url,
        dataType: "JSON",
        method: "GET",
        success: function(data)
        {
            //_data = data;
        }
    });
}
var data = pull_data('/abc/url');
```

and this is how my browser is showing the data

[image]

Now if I do `data.address` it says undefined

Comment: var obj = $.parseJSON(data);

Comment: `$.ajax` returns a jqXHR object, not the response from your server. Assuming you're actually retrieving a JSON object, instead of just plain text (it seems that way, since your dev tools show it like an object), in your `success` function, try `console.log(data.address)` and see if that logs. If you are, in fact, retrieving plain text instead of a JSON object, then `$.parseJSON` or `JSON.parse` would help.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var obj = JSON.parse(data);
console.log(obj.address)
```